# function after clicking on submit not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Whenever I try to run this script it say "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

```
<form name="abc" id="fform" class="contactform">
                    <p>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label><br /><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="input" /> <br/>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label><br /><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="input" /> 
                    </p>
            <input name="send" id="submit_btn" class="submit_btn"  type="submit" value="Join" />
                </form><!--end contact form-->
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(#fform).submit(function() {
                    alert("asd");
                });
});
    </script>
```

I am trying to create a function that when I click on submit it creates an ajax call to insert values into the database.

Comment: This is what syntax highlighting is for. See the string in alert is red? The parameter of your jQuery selector should be a string, and so it should be red too.

Comment: where is your ajax code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `id` in quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fform').submit(function() {
// ---^ here ^ ----------
        alert("asd");
    });
});
```